# How to have a common state between two React custom Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two custom Hooks for taking in an integer and either adding 1 or subtracting 1 to the value before returning it.  The value has to be shared between the two Hooks so that one can remember what the other has either added or subtracted.

```
function usePrevPage(page) {
    const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(page);
    const handleLastPage = () => {
        setLastPage(page => page - 1);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      handleLastPage();
    },[page]);
    return [lastPage, handleLastPage];
}

function useNextPage(page) {
    const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(page);
    const handleNextPage = () => {
        setNextPage(page => page + 1);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      handleNextPage();
    },[page]);
    return [nextPage, handleNextPage];
}
```

Currently, having the same variable conflicts with each other.  For example,

```
const [page, handleLastPage] = usePrevPage(2)
const [page, handleNextPage] = useNextPage(2)
```

is not allowed since `page` has already been declared on the first one.  How do I set up so that there is a common state between the two?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code, as it stands this doesn't look like something that should be done with state (or effects) at all.  It looks like you should just have a single state for page, and do `const nextPage = page + 1`, `const prevPage = page - 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one hook?

```
function usePage(initial) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(initial);
    return [page, () => setPage(page - 1), () => setPage(page + 1)];
}

//...
const [page, prev, next] = usePage(1);
```